# cannot find python module sql_driver

Tags: python

I normally have no problem scouring the web for obscure python packages. However I cannot find this one. Does anyone know what the error is referring too?

Is there an easy way to dig into the source to figure out what modules it wants?
I know I shouldn't be bugging stackoverflow about every missing module I have so is there a method for debugging this myself?

These are the modules i've most recently installed for this project:
blist
beautifulsoup
requests
pymongo
SQLAlchemy
xmltodict
financial_fundamentals

I think the error is coming from SQLAlchemy but the error readout says something about vector_cache

Using the following line:

```
import financial_fundamentals.accounting_metrics as ac
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f1aecf47aa1b> in <module>()
----> 1 import financial_fundamentals.accounting_metrics as ac

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\financialfundamentals-0.2.3-py2.7.egg\financial_fundamentals\accounting_metrics.py in <module>()
     65 import financial_fundamentals.edgar as edgar
     66 
---> 67 @vector_cache.vector_cache
     68 def earnings_per_share(required_data):
     69     start, end = required_data.index[0], required_data.index[-1]

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vector_cache-0.1.0-py2.7.egg\vector_cache\_vector_cache.pyc in vector_cache(user_function)
     19         # When the function name or location changes you're going to have to re-cache everything, bummer.
     20         metric = user_function.__name__
---> 21         data_store = get_data_store()
     22         @wraps(user_function)
     23         def wrapper(required_data_df):

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vector_cache-0.1.0-py2.7.egg\vector_cache\__init__.py in _get_data_store(cls)
     37         except IOError:
     38             # no config in home directory
---> 39             return cls._default_data_store(db_dir=home)
     40         else:
     41             return cls._eval_config_code(code)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\vector_cache-0.1.0-py2.7.egg\vector_cache\__init__.py in _default_data_store(db_dir)
     43     @staticmethod
     44     def _default_data_store(db_dir):
---> 45         from sql_driver import SQLDataStore
     46         import os
     47         db_file_path = os.path.join(db_dir, 'vector_cache.db')

ImportError: No module named sql_driver
```

Comment: How are you installing them? Are you using pip? If not you may want to look into it. You may be missing a module.

Comment: Seems that vector_cache is not correctly installed and can't find its own modules. Take a look [here](https://github.com/andrewkittredge/vector_cache/blob/master/vector_cache/sql_driver.py#L25)

Comment: I just used pip to uninstall and reinstall vector_cache which did not work. I reinstalled several times manually which did not work. I can import sql_driver manually so I edited the vector_cache source to import vector_cache.sql_driver instead of sql_driver which makes no sense even though it works perfectly